# Qual a diferença entre as medalhas "Altruísta" e "Investidor"?

Tags: suporte, medalhas

**Altruísta**: "Primeira gratificação concedida manualmente para uma pergunta de outra pessoa"

**Investidor**: "Primeira gratificação oferecida por você na pergunta de outra pessoa"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Investidor:** você *ofereceu* uma gratificação. Você ainda não pagou a gratificação.

**Altruísta:** você *pagou* a gratificação a uma pessoa.

Comment: Na verdade você paga adiantado (ao sistema), mas a ideia é essa mesmo. A primeira é por iniciar o processo de gratificação, e a segunda é por entregar o prêmio para uma das respostas.